# Why is my class instanceof check failing?

Tags: javascript, typescript

To me it seems that the object is an instance of `ChatRoom`, what am I missing here?

Class:

```js
export class ChatRoom {
  public id?: number;
  public name_of_chat_room: string;
  public chat_creator_user_id: number;
  public chat_room_is_active: 0 | 1;
  public chat_room_is_shareable: 0 | 1;
  public time_of_most_recent_message?: Date | string;
  public created_at?: Date | string;

  constructor(chatRoom: {
    name_of_chat_room: string;
    chat_creator_user_id: number;
    chat_room_is_active: 0 | 1;
    chat_room_is_shareable: 0 | 1;
    time_of_most_recent_message?: Date | string;
  }) {
    Object.assign(this, chatRoom);
  }
}
```

`finalResult` object that is failing:

```js
{
    name_of_chat_room: 'First Posted Chat Room',
    chat_creator_user_id: 21,
    chat_room_is_active: 1,
    chat_room_is_shareable: 1
  }
```

`if` statement that is not running:

```js
if (finalResult instanceof ChatRoom){
console.log("hooray")
}else{
console.log("foooey")
}
```

---

### Full code snippet

```ts
export class ChatRoom {
  public id ? : number;
  public name_of_chat_room: string;
  public chat_creator_user_id: number;
  public chat_room_is_active: 0 | 1;
  public chat_room_is_shareable: 0 | 1;
  public time_of_most_recent_message ? : Date | string;
  public created_at ? : Date | string;

  constructor(chatRoom: {
    name_of_chat_room: string;
    chat_creator_user_id: number;
    chat_room_is_active: 0 | 1;
    chat_room_is_shareable: 0 | 1;
    time_of_most_recent_message ? : Date | string;
  }) {
    Object.assign(this, chatRoom);
  }
}

let finalResult = {
  name_of_chat_room: 'First Posted Chat Room',
  chat_creator_user_id: 21,
  chat_room_is_active: 1,
  chat_room_is_shareable: 1
}

if (finalResult instanceof ChatRoom) {
  console.log("hooray")
} else {
  console.log("foooey")
}
```

Comment: Why would it be a `ChatRoom`? It's a plain object you created that happens to share some property names with `ChatRoom`. It might be valuable to take a step back and check out some JS OOP tutorials (specifically how classes work).

Comment: See [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) doesn't check whether an object has the same properties as a Class definition, but rather whether the object was declared with that constructor (or a constructor that inherits from it).

For instance:

```
var finalResult = new ChatRoom({
  name_of_chat_room: 'First Posted Chat Room',
  chat_creator_user_id: 21,
  chat_room_is_active: 1,
  chat_room_is_shareable: 1
});
finalResult instanceof ChatRoom
```

should return true

Comment: Ok thank you very much couldn't find that information